# Unresolved Inclusion: <jni.h> after ADT updated to 22

Tags: android

After an update of ADT to 22, I am getting these warnings all over c++ files, and the warning says Unresolved inclusion : Anybody have idea what might be causing it.

Note: There is no problem in building the code, however its annoying to see question marks and yellow lines all over the file